# How to filter for consecuting timeline events in pure SQL?

Tags: performance, mariadb, mariadb-10.3, query-performance

I run a LPR system on a parking lot, and I record every plate along with the camera that recorded it.

I have 2 cameras, camera 1 is on the entry and camera 2 on the exit. So for every reading I record the following on a table

```
Id|Camera|Plate|Timestamp
```

I need to run a query which returns every car who has not exited the parking lot. So the condition would be: I need to return every record which has an entry (`camera = 1`) not followed by an exit (`camera = 2`).

Which would be the best approach? I don't want to use cursors if possible.

Should I create 2 temp tables:

```
SELECT plate, MAX(Timestamp)
FROM records WHERE camera = 1 GROUP BY plate, MAX(timestamp)
```

one for each camera, then

```
SELECT temp1_entries except temp2_exits
```

and the result of the above query would be the cars who hasn't exited along with their entry timestamp.

DBMS is **MariaDB**, version **10.3.7**.

Is this approach correct? Is there a better approach?

Comment: This `GROUP BY MAX(timestamp)` looks buggy for me, probably it won't work, or if it will, it will do some very different thing.... this `WITH` is a very powerful thing.

Comment: MariaDb @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: @peterh I haven't actually tried my proposed solution, was just a train of thought.

Comment: Add the version as well, please. 5.3, 5.5? 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3?

Comment: Latest, 10.3.7.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need cursor for that.

If your `id` are automatically incrementing, you also don't need ordering by the timestamp, the `id` is enough. If not, then use timestamps. Note, timestamps have some possibility of funny effects (timezones, daylight saving times, simultaneous effects inside a single second and many similar "surprises").

This query filters those camera1 events, which are *not* followed by a camera2 event - either because the car is in the lot, or because they are tricking. The query handles also "funny" cases, for example, if a car would be detected by the camera on the *entrance* multiple times.

It does not handle the case somebody leaves the lot without entering it, but understanding the logic, it is easy to improve.

```
WITH Raw AS (
  SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Plate ORDER BY Id) AS EventNo,
  Id,
  Camera,
  Plate,
  Timestamp
  FROM CameraLog
)
SELECT Prev.*
FROM CameraLog AS Prev
LEFT JOIN CameraLog AS Next
  ON Prev.Plate = Next.Plate AND Prev.EventNo + 1 = Next.EventNo
WHERE Prev.Camera = 1 AND Next.Camera <> 1;
```

The logic is that first we extend the table with the "event history" order of a single car by the `RANK()` windowing function: the `Raw` subquery essentially extends the `CameraLog` table with a new, `EventNo` column. This column is essentially an auto-incrementing `id`, *but it is ordered for all the plates induvidually*.

In the second step, in the main query, we join this table with *itself together*. Essentially, we try to find for all event the next one.

The result is that we have such a table:

```
columns of camera events | columns of the consecuting camera event
```

In this column structure, it is already easy to filter with a `WHERE` (last line).

Note, this query will be highly suboptimal, if the size of the tables is in the order of the available RAM in your server. If you need to handle large data tables quickly, you will need more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with a rather simple query:

```
SELECT plate, timestamp
FROM records AS r
WHERE camera = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM records AS n
        WHERE n.camera = 2 
          AND n.plate = r.plate
          AND n.timestamp > r.timestamp
      ) ;
```

An index on `(camera, plate, timestamp)` would help efficiency.

---

A different method, using CTEs and window functions:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT plate, timestamp, camera, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY plate
                              ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rn   
    FROM records AS r
  )
SELECT plate, timestamp
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1              -- the last entry per plate
  AND camera = 1 ;        -- is "enter"
```

I think a different index - on `(plate, timestamp, camera)` - would be better for this query.